# React beautiful drag and drop doesn't work with Material UI component

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-beautiful-dnd

I've tried to make a horizontal list of MUI buttons draggable with [react beautiful drag and drop.](https://github.com/atlassian/react-beautiful-dnd) But it doesn't seem to be working.

I wrapped up my buttons with `<DragDropContext>`, `<Droppable>`,and `<Draggable>` tags.
Here's the code.

```
<DragDropContext>
  <Droppable droppableId="characters">
    {(provided, snapshot) => (
    <Stack
      direction="row"
      spacing="{1}"
      className="characters"
      {...provided.droppableProps}
      ref="{provided.innerRef}"
    >
      {[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9].map((x, index) => (
      <Draggable key="{x}" draggableId="{x}" index="{index}">
        {(provided, snapshot) => (
        <button
          variant="contained"
          ref="{provided.innerRef}"
          {...provided.draggableProps}
          {...provided.dragHandleProps}
        >
          {x}
        </button>
        )}
      </Draggable>
      ))}
    </Stack>
    )}
  </Droppable>
</DragDropContext>
```

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1VprPiCk-we5HVhvYzPPBEFdeHMX39BXC/view?usp=sharing

This is the result I've got. [Undraggable list of buttons]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see in this issue, [Buttons cannot be used as custom drag handles](https://github.com/atlassian/react-beautiful-dnd/issues/2296)

So in your case, you have to put a div outside buttons. And also, draggableId should be `string`.

```
<DragDropContext>
  <Droppable droppableId="characters">
    {(provided, snapshot) => (
      <Stack
        direction="row"
        spacing={1}
        className="characters"
        {...provided.droppableProps}
        ref={provided.innerRef}
      >
        {[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8].map((x, index) => (
          <Draggable key={x} draggableId={`${x}`} index={index}>
            {(provided, snapshot) => (
              <div
                ref={provided.innerRef}
                {...provided.draggableProps}
                {...provided.dragHandleProps}
              >
                <button variant="contained">{x}</button>
              </div>
            )}
          </Draggable>
        ))}
      </Stack>
    )}
  </Droppable>
</DragDropContext>;
```